# questions Custom Query Designer and Custom Data Processing Extensions

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to put the "final touches" on a  Custom Query Designer (CQD) VS2013 and Custom Data Processing Extensions (CDPE) 2012 SQL Server project(s).

Questions:

1. For CDPE, does anyone have any examples supporting MultipleActiveResultSets?
2. For CDPE, is there the ability to cache data source connections and SSO returns?  So if a report has 15 data sources and 10 are the SAME, can I control that I don't make those additional 9 connections AND associated SSO calls? (Both in Visual Studio 2013 and in production mode (pure SSRS reports)? The SSO calls are part of the CDPE.
3. CQD, how do I control the ability to invoke the "Define Query Parameters" window ON DEMAND? (Visual Studio 2013 -> 2012 SQL Server)? (although I hate myself for cross-posting, I need to get an answer for this ASAP: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/44f55664-7255-465a-b6a4-561db222f850/custom-query-designer-open-define-query-parameters-on-demand-for-stored-procedure-scenario?forum=sqlreportingservices )
4. How do I get the Parameters from an existing report datasource (i.e. Stored Procedure)? (using the CQD)  FOUND ANSWER --> SqlCommandBuilder.**DeriveParameters(sqlCmd)**;

Thanks

Rob

PS Other than these questions, I have an end-to-end functional application for XML, SQL Server text/table/stored procedure.
PPS Microsoft forums where a complete waste of time: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e98cea92-dcea-46ae-a6d1-80c0ec0b3883?outputAs=rss

item# 4 update 1/27/2015:
For item# 3, it looks like the "root cause" is really a bug in Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners

(Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91)

It looks like class QueryParametersRequestedEventArgs, method QueryParametersRequestedEventArgs is not returning persisted values for parameters (i.e. it's returning the parameter list, but all values are coming back as null).

1. So if you've enabled the EventHandler
2. You load IDbCommand from your custom UI
3. It loads in what you'd expect it to load (which was persisted for the EXISTING DataSource), minus parameter values.

Comment: for item# 3 above, I'm trying to invoke this dialog from this kind of logic:

Comment: for item# 1, it looks like Microsoft hard-wired the DLL such that Default is not an option:

#region Assembly Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll, v11.0.0.0
// c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll
#endregion

using System;

namespace Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataProcessing
{
    public enum CommandBehavior
    {
        SingleResult = 1,
        SchemaOnly = 2,
    }
}

Comment: for item# 4

one note about this, there should have been some means to pull this from EXISTING parameters (if a DataSource ALREADY has persisted these).

i'm still working through the details as to on how this can be achieved (and will keep the forum posted as needed)